# How can I avoid parent class destructor to set a derived class' data member

Tags: c++

```
class parent {
    virtual ~parent();
private:
    int father_private;
    int common;
}

~parent() {
    common = 1;
}

class child: public parent {
    ~child();
private:
    int common;
}

~child() {
    common = 2;
}
```

with the logic above, the following steps are expected:

1. ~child() is called => child's common = 2.
2. ~parent() is called => parent's common = 1 ?

In step 2, "is this common = child's common"?

I found the address is not the same so it may mean compiler does not take the name but the offeset within the class. So the assignment of step 2 may write 1 to an unknown address and make unexpected crash, am I right?

I found Andorid native flow have some classes whose constructor or destructor to access its private data members. It makes inheritence extremely difficult as the problem above. How do you resolve this problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `virtual ~child()` still calls `~parent()` after itself ends, doesn't it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If base class destructor is `virtual`, then the derived class destructor is automatically `virtual` too

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
class child: public parent {
    ...
    int common;
}
```

Defines a **distinct** `int` named `common` in the class `child`.  Because the base class has any symbol named `common`, that base symbol is simply *hidden*.

It doesn't matter if the base symbol `parent::common` is an `int` or `std::string` or a function name or an enum.  It's hidden.

> in step 2, "is this common = child's common"??

No.  In the `parent` function, it's the parent's `common`.

> So the assignment of step 2 may write 1 to an unknown address & make unexpected crash, am I right??

No.  One assignment assigns to `parent::common`.  The other assigns to `child::common`.  They are two distinct variables.